# In a fixed mortgage, is the term the same as the amortization period?

Tags: mortgage, canada, real-estate, terminology

From what I understand, the term is the length of time the mortgage agreement and interest rate will be in effect and the amortization period is the length of time it’d take to fully pay off the loan. In the case of a fixed loan, lets say a 30 year, wouldn't the interest rate be in effect for the entirety of the 30 years (since its fixed/same) thus meaning that the term is also 30 years (same as the amortization period)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unusual for Canadian mortgages to have the same term and amortization. It's typical to have a 5 year term and a 25 year amortization, for example.

But rather than guessing what the term is (such as thinking, "it's probably the same as the amortization"), the correct thing to do is ask (or look at the offer.) The interest rate will depend on the term, since in a time when rates are moving, holding yours still is either something you need to pay for or be compensated for. This graph is from [ratehub](https://www.ratehub.ca/mortgage-term), a private site that compares Canadian interest rates:

[image]

A [government of Canada page](https://www.canada.ca/en/financial-consumer-agency/services/mortgages/mortgage-terms-amortization.html) that defines words related to mortgages says:

> Most mortgage holders in Canada have a mortgage term of 5 years or less, also known as a shorter-term mortgage. The shorter the term, the sooner you renew your mortgage contract.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that even if its a fixed mortgage the interest rate can change every term? I thought that a fixed mortgage meant the interest rate doesn't change for the entire amortization period. And if that's the case, then what's the difference between a fixed and an ARMs.

Comment: It's fixed **for the term** of the mortgage. So if you have a 5-year term, it's fixed for 5 years. Only a 1 year term? Only fixed for a year. Things like penalties for paying off early etc are also term by term: whenever the term ends you can pay it off if you like, that sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, thanks :)

Comment: Essentially they're *forcing* you to refinance every *X* years.  How odd...

Comment: @RonJohn There are other factors, but primarily, in Canada there is legislation that limits a bank's ability to charge penalty interest for long-term mortgages, increasing the risk of offering something over 5 years in term.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon like increasing the rate due to slow payment?

Comment: @RonJohn What I had meant to say was - penalty interest on early termination of the mortgage. So the risk to the banks for long-term interest rate volatility is heightened if borrowers can renegotiate when rates drop, at a capped penalty level.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon "at a capped penalty level" confuses me, because "risk to the banks for long-term interest rate volatility is heightened if borrowers can renegotiate when rates drop" looks just like the refinancing that Americans do all the time

Comment: @RonJohn Here's a quick summary [no affiliation] https://www.mondaq.com/canada/real-estate-and-construction/132798/prepayment-rights-under-the-interest-act In short - penalties for mortgages longer than 5 years are capped at 3 months of interest. I presume that penalties for early payment in the US are quite higher [though I don't know this for a fact].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon ahh... **early payment** penalties.  I thought those were a long-dead relic.

Comment: Just consider the sad plight of a new homeowner with a Canadian-style 30 year amortization, five year term home mortgage, with an interest rate and monthly payments that he can just manage..  Then, in the last 18 months of the mortgage, rates begin to rise higher and higher, as does the payment needed for the renewed mortgage..  A slow motion train wreck

Comment: That's why there are stress tests to qualify for mortgages here. You have to qualify for a higher rate than you actually pay. I understand that anything different feels weird and scary - that's how I feel about US mortgages. I got my first mortgage at a time of 20% rates, so the thought of being locked into that rate terrifies me more than your worry of not being locked in for 25 or 30 years. The truth is everyone is used to their own system and thinks it's normal. No please, no more comments that the Canadian system is awful.

Comment: @KateGregory You lost me at "… It's typical to have a 5 year term and a 25 year amortization…" whether that's special to Canada or not.

It reads as though broadly, you're saying it's typical for the term of the agreement to be different from the term of the mortgage. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, in Canada, that is typical. I am not answering for the rest of the world. The question is tagged Canada and I have said what is typical for Canada, and provided two references (one a government one) to back that up.